# How to adapt jQuery load to use multiple variables?

Tags: php, jquery

Apologies for the unclear title. I was unsure how to phrase the question.

I have a table which displays my highscore. I retrieve the highscore through this:

```
function topScore() {
      $( '#tableid tbody' ).load( 'm1.php' );
}
```

This is linked to a php file (m1.php):

```
<?php

   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XX','XX','XX');

   if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   } else {

   $sql="SELECT name, bet FROM m1 ORDER BY bet DESC LIMIT 5";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $bet = $row['bet']; 

      echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>CC$bet</td></tr>"; 

       }
   }
   mysqli_close($con);  

?>
```

This grabs the top 5 from a table named m1, which holds high scores.

I need to adapt the jQuery load so that it can load the high scores from different tables, depending on a variable, and without creating a separate high score php file for every table. I currently have a variable which varies from m1-m5. How can I rewrite it so, depending on the value of this variable, it grabs the high scores from the table named that variable? If I was sending information, I was just pass over a string... but this is a load, so I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this.

I apologise if anything I've said seems ridiculous. I'm very new to all of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function , accept another parameter called `data` , which holds your parameters which you want to send to the server side ,

```
function topScore() {
      $( '#tableid tbody' ).load( 'm1.php', {tableName: 'xxxx', method: 'POST'} );
}
```

so you can handle your parameters in your server side (php) through the `$_POST` , and if your `method` was set to GET so you will have to use `$_GET` in your php

**Important Note** , you should take care and do the necessary validation to protect your self from any kind of sql injections , it's recommended to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: So, through using this, I could handle it like `$tableName = strval($_POST['tableName']);` ? @HassanAhmed

Comment: yes , but you have to make extra validation to prevent any kind of sql injections

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use json in other words send the whole $result as its by

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Using ajax to get the data to javascript

```
$.ajax{
     url: "m1.php",
     type:  post,
     data: $.param({
             mode: "data"//send this as post in other words on php file (url) just $_POST["mode"] = "data";
     }),
     dataType: "json",
     success : function(data){
              //use the object data
      }
}
```

This is unclear you get the idea.use ajax to get load of data form php in addition the page does not reload.